# Restore revision history of a copied file using Perforce

Tags: version-control, perforce, revision-history

I copied a bunch of java classes into another java package outside of perforce by accident and  made a bunch of changes to them. I now realised that the revision history of those files has been lost as I didn't use perforce to copy the files over.

```
Example:
original file - dir1/Class1.java 
copied file - dir2/Class1.java
```

The original file still exists.

If I want to restore the revision history of the files what would be the appropriate command to run in order to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should have branched the file in Perforce rather than copied it outside of Perforce, but that can be remedied.

1. Copy `dir2/Class1.java` to another location then delete the original
2. Branch `dir1/Class1.java` to `dir2/Class1.java`
3. Check out `dir2/Class1.java`
4. Copy the backup of the file you made in step 1. to `dir2/Class1.java`
5. Check in `dir2/Class1.java`

You will then have your recent modifications to the file `dir2/Class1.java` in version control and the file will be linked to its original via the branch history.